# Questions regarding the notation used when referring to a set of ordered pairs

Tags: elementary-set-theory, notation

First let's define a set of "normal" elements (i.e. not a set of ordered pairs):

$A=\{x\in \mathbb{N}:x>10\}$

Let's call it the "first" definition. I can also define set A and its elements' properties in another way:

$\forall x(x\in A \iff x\in \mathbb{N} \land x>10)$

I can call this the "second" definition, and I know that it is equivalent to the first one.

Now let's try a set of ordered pairs.

$B=\{(x,y)\in \mathbb{N}\times\mathbb{N}:x>y\}$

So far so good. But I am unsure about how to proceed with the second "definition" similiar to the first example. Here is what I have tried:

$\forall x(x \in B \iff x\in \mathbb{N}\times\mathbb{N} \land x_1>x_2)$, where $x_1$ and $x_2$ refer to the first and second element of the ordered pair, though it does feel "informal" to be refering to them in such a way.

$\forall x \forall y((x,y)\in B \iff (x,y)\in \mathbb{N}\times\mathbb{N} \land x>y)$ is another thing I've tried. This one sounds more formal but less intuitive, as I haven't even defined a variable that refers to the element (ordered pair) of set B.

Are my methods correct? Is there something I can improve, or another method I haven't thought of? Am I completely missing the point? Sorry if this is a dumb question, and thank you in advance!

Comment: I don't see why the second method would be an issue. Elements can be ordered pairs, after all. (When you boil everything down, it's all just sets anyways; some sets are just fancier than others.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this is mostly just nitpicking, because at the end of the day, as long as people understand that the indexes refer to the first and second element it is fine, but if you wish to avoid that, here is how you can do it:

$\forall x\big(x \in B \Leftrightarrow \exists y \in \mathbb{N} \ \exists z\in \mathbb{N}(x=(y,z) \land y>z) \big)$

Answer (score 4):

Here's an option:

$\forall x(x \in B \iff \exists x_1\,\exists x_2\,( x_1\in\mathbb N)\land (x_2\in\mathbb N)\land (x=(x_1,x_2)) \land (x_1>x_2))$,